# всплывающее окно при закрытии страницы

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Необходимо, чтобы при закрытии web-страницы появлялось уведомление.
Происходить это должно многократно, чтобы затруднить закрытие самой страницы.

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Через onbeforeunload, только вот более одного раза не получится, и в некоторых браузерах эта возможность уже отключена именно из-за таких как вы.

Answer (score 1):

Никак.

Иначе нас бы давно уже заспамили рекламой эротического содержания и онлайн казино.

Comment: они и спамят, только это можно закрыть, но проблематично

Comment: приведи пример. Я пока только скрытие курсора могу выдумать, но это ж явный бред                                                 
<div id="nocursor"><!-- some stuff --></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('nocursor').style.cursor = 'none';
</script>

Comment: ооо, это тоже круто, я сейчас погуглю и найду сайт с такой хренью